# Multiple commands on Nagios remote host

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have a machine monitored by nagios that has the following line in nrpe.cfg

include_dir=/etc/nagios/cfgs/

The 'cfgs' dir consists of following files with various commands.

- servers.cfg
- database.cfg
- regular.cfg

However, some commands are repeated among these cfg files but they differ in the arguments. Eg: check_disk command on database has different threshold and on servers have different threshold for the same command.

My question is: If there are multiple definitions of a command, which command is picked up by nrpe? Is there some way to identify it?

Answer (score 0):

You generally can not have duplication in command names in your nrpe.cfg files - though no error is thrown if there are duplicates.  I've had this happen before (accidentally) with very large configs, and nrpd has always chosen to use the very LAST matching command it found.  In my case, being a single config file, it was always easy to spot the LAST matching command in the file.  With many included files, this could be an issue.  I believe it would load these files in alphabetical order with the include_dir command you provided.

In any case, I'd look for more unique names for these duplicates.  Such as 'check_disk_db' for the one checking database disks.  These names can be just about anything you want them to be - but remember to change them on the Nagios side as well.  Using unique command names would make your life as a Nagios admin much easier.

As far as figuring out which is actually being used.  You can turn on debugging.  The debugging output doesn't include the file the command came from, but does show you what options were passed and exactly which actual commands where executed via the check command.  This info should be enough to see which nrpe command was selected.